# Vue - using $emit, .sync pattern with not required props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

If I have a non-required prop is it possible to emit (using `$emit('update:<prop name>', value)` ) it in the child component and have it update to the emitted value without the parent component having `:<prop name>.sync="<data name>"`

example child component:

```
Vue.component('child-component', {
  props: {
    bar: {
      type: String,
      default: () => 'foo'
    }
  },

  methods: {
    doSomethingWithBar () {
      this.$emit('update:bar', 'bar')
    }
  },

  template: '<button @click="doSomethingWithBar">{{ bar }}</button>'
})
```

example parent:

```
<child-component /> <!-- notice no :bar.sync -->
```

Example on codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXaGJg

My current solution is:

```
Vue.component('child-component', {
  props: {
    bar: {
      type: String,
      default: () => 'foo'
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      innerBar: null
    }    
  },

  mounted () {
    this.innerBar = this.bar
  },

  methods: {
    doSomethingWithBar () {
      this.innerBar = 'bar'
    }
  },

  template: '<button @click="doSomethingWithBar">{{ bar }}</button>',

  watch: {
    bar () {
      this.innerBar = this.bar
    },

    innerBar () {
      if (this.innerBar !== this.bar) {
        this.$emit('update:bar', this.innerBar)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But this requires a lot of unnecessary code and I am quite sure there is a better idea.

UPDATE: (Actual context)

I am designing an audio component that wraps controls and playing Audio.

Example for `audio.loop` (I would have to do something similar to currentTime, paused, volume, etc.):

```
export default {
  props: {
    loop: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: () => false
    },
    audio: {
      required: true,
      type: HTMLAudioElement
    },
  },

  data () {
    return {
      innerLoop: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleLoop () {
      if (this.innerLoop) {
        this.innerLoop = false
      } else {
         this.innerLoop = true
      }
    }
  },

  watch: {
    loop () {
      this.innerLoop = this.loop
    },

    innerLoop () {
      this.audio.loop = this.innerLoop
      if (this.innerLoop !== this.loop) {
        this.$emit('update:loop', this.innerLoop)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works but is there a better way?

Comment: why are you doing that? your prop `bar` looks like an inner data item

Comment: My actual code is an audio component that wraps around the HTML audio API. I would like to have a prop for `currentTime` that gets displayed in the component, updated using `'timeupdate'` event, and I would like the user of the component to be able to set the `currentTime` through a prop

Comment: So you want the source of truth for the current time to be in two places? Either set through the `timeupdate` event or by the user through props? Or do you want the prop to only act as an initial, default value? Why not pull out the current time display into its own component, and have only the parent manage the time? The parent can then update the time directly, or from the event. It seems like you've simplified your question so much that all context is lost, and it looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Well, it would completely ruin the use of the component if the parent had to manage the time, because the parent may have hundreds of these components. When the parent sets `currentTime` it should override the `audio.currentTime` - kinda like the user seeking to a certain time by clicking.

Comment: @chipit24 I've added some context, maybe it will explain better